# Copy the values of multiple columns of a dataframe into 1 column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
    ID  a1 a2 b1 b2
    1   
    2
    3
    4
    ... 
    300
```

I would like to create a new dataframe merging columns a1 a2 and b1, b2. The aim is to obtain something like this:

```
     ID  a  b 
     1   
     2
     3
     4
     ... 
     600
```

where a is basically given by the two columns a1, a2 one after the other.
any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: ... in another words add some data with expected output, now thre are spaces only.

Comment: Hello Luca, would you like to merge columns 2 by 2 or by letter ?

Comment: HI, see the example below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Take temporary dataframe like this

```
df1[["a", "b"]]=df[["a1", "b1"]]
df2[["a", "b"]]=df[["a2", "b2"]]
```

This will give two dataframes and after that concat both

```
new_df=pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

It does work, actually, but I am wondering if there is a faster solution. here is the code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss'])
df5 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss'])
df6 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss'])
df7 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss'])
df8 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss'])
df9 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss'])

df1[["CNTR_CODE", 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss']]=copy_df[["CNTR_CODE", 'Risk_damage0','pot_tot_loss00', 'annual_tot_loss00']]
df2[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss']]=copy_df[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss01','annual_tot_loss01']]
df3[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss']]=copy_df[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss02','annual_tot_loss02']]

df4[["CNTR_CODE", 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss']]=copy_df[["CNTR_CODE", 'Risk_damage1','pot_tot_loss10', 'annual_tot_loss10']]
df5[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss']]=copy_df[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss11','annual_tot_loss11']]
df6[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss']]=copy_df[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss12','annual_tot_loss12']]

df7[["CNTR_CODE", 'Risk_damage', 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss']]=copy_df[["CNTR_CODE", 'Risk_damage2','pot_tot_loss20', 'annual_tot_loss20']]
df8[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss']]=copy_df[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss21','annual_tot_loss21']]
df9[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss','annual_tot_loss']]=copy_df[["CNTR_CODE", 'pot_tot_loss22','annual_tot_loss22']]


new_df=pd.concat([df1, df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9]).reset_index()
```